# Convert DateTime Format in Web API

Tags: c#, odata, webapi

We exposed a Web API with OData protocol. The issue we had is that customer sends requests with a defined DateTime format. Something like this: `2020-10-10T10:21+02:00`. How we could convert this date to this format `2020-10-10T12:21`? Is it possible to be done in *WebAPIConfig*? or it should be done in controllers part? How it could be reached?

Comment: check out this https://vikutech.blogspot.com/2017/05/elegantly-dealing-with-timezones-in-mvc-core-webapi.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the method .ToString() with the correct parameter on the Datetime object in the controller to get the format that u want to use.

[Example of datetime formats .ToString()](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)