# C# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API: change DateTime format to customize

Tags: c#, linq, datetime-format, .net-7.0

I would like to ask what else can I try?

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API with C# and I'm trying to change a field named `Startdate` which is of type `DateTime` from the database to customize its format.

The field's format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss (CE.)`, and when output to Swagger Json I got `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`.

What I want is `YYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss (ROC.)`.

I had tried to set it type as string in the view model, and in implement, I got it from LINQ but failed...

My view model:

```
public class ABCViewModel 
{
    public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation in the action method:

```
public async Task<List<ABCViewModel>> RetrieveAllAsync()
{
    List<ABCViewModel> ABC = new List<ABCViewModel>();

    try
    {
        var aa = await dbABC.tableABC
            .Select(st
                => new ABCViewModel
                        {
                            startDate = st.Startdate.Value.ToString()
                        })
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.startDate)
            .ToListAsync();

        return aa;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "RetrieveAllAsync Error");
    }

    return ABC;
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ABCController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IABC abc;

    public ABCController(IABC abc)
    {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    // GET: api/<ABCController>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<ABCViewModel>> GetABC()
    {
        
        var result = await abcService.RetrieveAllAsync();        
        return result;
    }        
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IABC
{
    Task<List<ABCViewModel>> RetrieveAllAsync();
}
```

So sorry for my wrong grammar and strange description, hope the code I provide can somewhat help me describe...

If there is anything else can I do, I would appreciate it.

Thank you for your help.

What I had tried:

1. changed:

   ```
    startDate = st.Startdate.Value.ToString()
   ```

   (if use this, only got CE.: DD-M YY)

   to:

   ```
    startDate = (st.Startdate.Value.Year - 1911).ToString() + "/"
       + st.Startdate.Value.Month + "/"
       + st.Startdate.Value.Day + " "
   + st.Startdate.Value.Hour + ":"
   + st.Startdate.Value.Minute + ":"
   + st.Startdate.Value.Second
   ```

Got:

```
112/1/1 0:0:0
```

I want:

```
112/01/01 00:00:00
```

(Nearly!

2.
Add:
`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = " {0:yyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} ")]` above `public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }`

But nothing changed.

3.
Add:
`.AsEnumerable()`

To change to:

```
var abc = await dbABC.tableABC
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.startDate)
            .ToListAsync()
        .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(st
                => new ABCViewModel
                        {
                            startDate = st.Startdate.Value.ToString(),
                            
                        });
```

Got:
`AsEnumerable()` only can use at `ToList()`, `ToListAsync()` cannot use it.

4.
I would like to change my code as:
[stackoverflow01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103218/12102935)

But because my work has collaborator, so I cannot do it to avoid other got any problem.

5.
I found that:
[stackoverflow02](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427207/12102935)

so I tried to change format on my Controller but maybe I failed because I didn’t have enough ability.

Comment: _"The field's format is"_ - No, it's not. `DateTime` is basically a number. You only apply a format, when you turn it into a human readable string. How to specify that format is _very well documented_.

Comment: @RolandMai : Nope, I got an error at catch{} : System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<tableABC>()
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Startdate.Value.ToString("{0:yyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}"))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.ToString' failed.

I think that my LINQ maybe cannot do ToString(...) ?

Comment: @Fildor Number? I didn't find this at all, thank you very much, I will look for a solution based on this!

Comment: Yes under the hood, it is just a number. To format it refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @Fildor I browsed it for some try, but my linq cannot accept any argument I send to `ToString()` for cannot translate ToString. But for so, I may be close to the correct solution...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my error!

Only change my Implementation in the action method of try{}:

```
try
{
    var aa = await dbABC.tableABC
        .Select(st
            => new ABCViewModel
                    {
                        startDate = st.Startdate.Value.ToString()
                    })
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.startDate)
        .ToListAsync();

    return aa;
}
```

to

```
try
{
    var aa = await (from st in dbABC.tableABC
                    orderby st.Startdate descending
                    select new DisasterViewModel
                     {
                         startDate = st.Startdate.Value.ToString("yyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                     }                             
                   ).ToListAsync();

    return aa;
}
```

will successful.

Really unexpected!
Thanks for @RolandMai and @Fildor helps, perhaps I got a little ability on LINQ...?

Comment: I'm guess this is working because it can do the inital select and order by on the database, and is doing the .net formating in memory.

Comment: @cjb110 Now I get it! Thank you very much for your explanation!